# Disable Controls if the Control Name is in the Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I hope this question enlightens me about my problem and don't lead me to negative posts.

I will try my best to explain the question.

Here it is.

I have a datagridview and it looks like this

[image]

and I have a `MainForm` with the following controls and they are

```
PictureBox2
PictureBox3
PictureBox4
PictureBox5
PictureBox6
PictureBox7
```

As what you see on the image above on the column `Control Name` is the same name in my `MainForm`

and as far as I know in VB.Net that **All** or if not **Most** of the controls Enable is True and False so as what you see on the Image Above the column `Access` has a value of True and False.

Now this is my Question: How can I Find the controls in `MainForm` and Enable\Disable it based on Datagridview? I mean find the control name based on whats in Datagridview and Enable Disable it.

I hope you get my point and If im right the code would likely look like this

```
  Sub MenuControls()
        'Sample but not working
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            "Control Name".Enabled = "Access"
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Me.Controls.Find <- have a look along this path.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer its hard to understand :(

Comment: Like this: MainForm.Controls.Find("PictureBox7") . You can find some documentation herE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Find);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the row cell's values happens using the Name of the column as Indexer in the Cells collection. Then finding the relative control can be done using the Form (Me) controls collection

```
Public Sub EnablePictures()
    Dim Enable As Boolean
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Enable = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("Access").Value)
        Dim ctrl = Me.Controls(row.Cells("Control Name").Value)
        if ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
            ctrl.Enabled = Enable
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code makes a lot of assumptions. First you columns should be exactly named as appears in your image (I see the Header caption, not the real column name) and then I assume that you have the PictureBoxes as childs of the forms controls collection. If they are contained in a different control (groupbox, panel...) you should use the Controls collection of that container.

I have created a Sub from the previous code to help you in your problem stated in the comments below. In this way you could call this sub whenever you need it. So if you add picurebox controls dynamically you can call the sub just after adding them to your form

Comment: Wow THANK YOU SO SO MUCH :D

Comment: Sir I have a question, Do you think it will have an error if the controls cannot be find? lets say that the form is not yet open. something like that

Comment: Yes, if the controls are not yet in the controls collection you will get an exception. You could solve the problem assigning the return with _Dim ctrl = Me.Controls("....")_ to a temporary variable and then check with an _If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then_ run the enabling code

Comment: I dont know how to do that i think its too hard :(